# how can i close mysql connection including DB name after execute a function using OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am learning on PHP and i have a basic knowledge on php. I am facing a problem that is,

I want to clear the database connection cause i am working on a demo project for my skill improvement. But this site is to slow.So that i want to clear db connection after execute any page.I am trying last 2 days, still searching.

PLEASE HELP...

Here is my class file **db_connect.php**

```
    class Db_connect {
    public function database_connection() {
        $host_name = 'localhost';
        $user_name = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $db_name = 'product_management';
        $db_con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $db_name);
        if (!$db_con) {
            die('Connection Fail' . mysqli_error($db_con));
        }
        return $db_con;
    }
}
```

Here is my class file **soft_info.php** 
which is include some function-

```
    class Soft_info extends Db_connect{

    public $link;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->link = $this->database_connection();
    }

    public function search_model_info($model_id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sw_info ORDER BY s.sw_id DESC";
        if (mysqli_query($this->link, $sql)) {
            $query_result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
            return $query_result;
        } else {
            die('Query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making another DB wrapper? Just use a [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) objects. And the disconnect will automatically be called in the destructor (which you dont need to execute manually, because it is done by garbage collector).

Comment: Closing the connection to MySQL won't make the site faster. It does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks you boss,

Answer (score -1):

for example:

```
mysqli_close($this->link);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: Thanks you boss for your feedback. 
i used this but it shows unexpected. and add a destructor function to solve this problem. but im not sure its good or bad. 
public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }

i used this in every class. Is it good and works well. thank you for your valuable comment..